# AWS SDK S3 missing credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

Trying to use the aws-sdk node module, but I keep getting a missing cradentials error when trying to upload a file to my bucket.

Here is the error from my server:

```
8:16:09 AM web.1 |  CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config
8:16:09 AM web.1 |      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/reid/Desktop/DupeFinder/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:83:34)
8:16:09 AM web.1 |      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
8:16:09 AM web.1 |      at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
8:16:09 AM web.1 |      at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:208:7)
8:16:09 AM web.1 |      at Socket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:706:34)
8:16:09 AM web.1 |      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
8:16:09 AM web.1 |      at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
8:16:09 AM web.1 |      at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
8:16:09 AM web.1 |      at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:410:8)
8:16:09 AM web.1 |      at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
8:16:09 AM web.1 |      at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
8:16:09 AM web.1 |      at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
```

And here is my backend that is giving me that error:

```
let s3 = new aws.S3()

app.use(express.static('./public'))
 aws.config = new aws.Config();
let myCredentials = new aws.CognitoIdentityCredentials({IdentityPoolId:'IDENTITY_POOL_ID'}); 
aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "xxxxxx",
    secretAccessKey: "xxxxxx",
    region: 'us-east-1';
})

var upload = multer({
  storage: mults3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'dupefinderuseruploads',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString())
    }
  })
})



app.post('/uploads', upload.single('Ncsv'), function(req, res, next) {
     res.send('Successfully uploaded ' + req.files.length + ' files!')
})
```

I blanked out the access key and secret key, im not actually using xxxxxx..

Anyway. I think i just need to add a cradentials key in aws.config.update, but firstly, idk what the key for that object is, and secondly, idk where to find the value of that key in amazon s3.

P.S. im using multerS3 because i originally built the app with multer and it worked. using multers3 here is not the issue.

Could someone point me in the right direction with this? I'm not too sure where to go look, and googling this is seeming to be a dead end.

I have this myCredintials var that was shown in the docs, but I can't tell exactly what that var is doing.

Comment: Have you tried confirming the S3 creds are hooked up correctly by making a few S3 calls via the AWS-SDK? That will rule out whether it's an issue with the aws-sdk either as a bug or a configuration error. If it works fine there, then you know it's a multer-S3 issue.

Comment: No, I had to create an identity pool.

Comment: Creating an identitypool via amazon cognito using an example code doc they have took away that error, but not im getting the error: TypeError: Key must be a buffer.